# Unallocated space cannot be used for other partitions

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

Some weeks ago I installed the latest Ubuntu OS version on my PC. I gave it 12GB of space and then 4GB for the hibernation temp storage. Yesterday I realized that I wasn't going to use it any more so I went to "Disk Management" in Windows 7 and deleted both partitions. When I restarted I got a boot error that I fixed using a command in my Windows Repair Disk. So since I had free space I want it to extend that space to my storage partition that I created by shrinking C, however it doesn't let me extend. I also deleted my Storage partition to see if both unallocated space united but nothing.

What can I do to make use of this free space?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your disk within `Disk Management` I am going to guess your trying to extend the incorrect disk.

Comment: I can't it tells me that I need 10 reputation to put a picture but it basically looks like C, Javier Storage ( Primary Partition), and Unllocated Space at the beggining of both partition and it's black

Comment: You can post a link to the image; I can't help you without it.